# How do I limit search paramter only to one column in datatables only when using URL paramter

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am working on a datatable where I need to limit the search to one column **only when using paramater**.
example:abc.com?search=test. But, **if not passing parameter, it should search all columns**. How do I achieve this? Here is the code I have.
Here is the fiddle: http://live.datatables.net/piquxewa/1/edit

Javascript

```
function getUrlVars() {
      var vars = [], hash;
      var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
      for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
      {
          hash = hashes[i].split('=');
          vars.push(hash[0]);
          vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
      }
      return vars;
  } 
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var searchTerm = getUrlVars()['search'];
    var table = $('#example1').DataTable( {
      responsive: true,
      paging: false,
      searching: true,
      lengthChange: false,
      bInfo: false,
      bSort: true,
"columnDefs": [
    { "searchable": false, "targets": 0 }
  ],

      search: {
        search: searchTerm
      }
   });
  });

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<h2>Datatable 2</h2>

<table id="example1" class="row-border stripe dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" style=" width: 100%;"><thead>
<tr role="row">
<th style=" width: 11%;">Date</th>
<th style=" width: 23%;">Name</th>
<th style=" width: 23%;">Type</th>
<th style=" width: 23%;">Topic</th>
<th style=" width: 20%;">Hidden</th>
</tr>

</thead><tbody>
<tr>
<td>Current</td>
<td>John Doe</td>
<td>ABC</td>
<td>Test</td>
<td>orange, banana</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Current</td>
<td>Baby</td>
<td>ABC</td>
<td>Test</td>
<td>orange, banana</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Current</td>
<td>Joe</td>
<td>ABC</td>
<td>Test</td>
<td>orange, banana</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Current</td>
<td>John</td>
<td>ABC</td>
<td>Test</td>
<td>orange, banana</td>
</tr>




</tbody></table>
</div>


</html>
```

Comment: Add also the `datatables` tag to your question, as it's more a DataTables related matter (indeed it has nothing to do with **html** or **css**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood well, you want the `searchable` option to be set to `true` for column 0 **ONLY IF** exists a search term for the `search=` GET parameter, right?

Otherwise, you want to set it to `false`.

That's how you can achieve it with a ***ternary operator***:

```
"columnDefs": [
  { "searchable": searchTerm === undefined ? false : true, "targets": 0 }
  ],
```

Comment: Thankyou very much. It worked very well. Is there a way to define dolumndef twice? I also need this default on page display. However datatables is ignoring the request. maybe a conflict?                                                                                                                   
         columnDefs: [            
            {
                "targets": [ 3 ],
                "visible": false
            }
        ],

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple objects inside the `columnDefs[]` array (it's an array, after all). Each object will contain specific rules (*visible*, *searchable*, *orderable*, etc.) that will be applied to the `targets:` column/s defined in the same object. If there are conflicting rules applied to the same column (i.e. same *target*) the first defined will prevail.